# What do we know about $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been reading notes about algebraic groups and I feel like I am missing something about $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}$). What do we know about this group?
Trivially, the determinant of these matrixes must be $1$ or $-1$. But do we know something else?
More specifically, how does it act on $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The determinant must be $\pm1$. If $A\in GL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ and $p\in {\Bbb{Z}}^n$ then $Ap$ (matrix multiplication) is an action.

Comment: The determinant must be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, so it can be $1$ or $-1$. Requiring the determinant to be $1$ gives $SL_n$, not $GL_n$.

Comment: Are you not sure how $n$ by $n$ matrices act on vectors with $n$ components?

Comment: I've given your question a more descriptive title.  In general, your title should describe exactly what your question is rather than saying something vague.  Rule of thumb: if your question's title contains the word "question", it is bad.

Answer (score 2):

The group $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is an *arithmetic group*, and there is large literature on such groups. A gentle introduction to this area is, among others, the [book](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063) by Dave Witte Morris. 
So we do know something else about this group, and indeed quite a lot.
As an example, arithmetic groups are finitely presented and have only finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups (Borel and Harish-Chandra). Every polycyclic group can be embedded into $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for some $n$; the automorphism group of a finitely generated nilpotent group is isomorphic to an arithmetic group. And so on.

It is also worth mentioning the field of *crystallographic groups*, which is closely related to the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which is precisely $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Furthermore the cohomology of arithmetic groups is studied intensively in the field of automorphic forms and the Langlands program.